# Displaying background image with correct ratio

Tags: css

I have got a container with two background-images on the left and right side of it.
The left image should be shown with height 100%, and the right image with width 50%.
The image itself has a high resolution and I want them to be displayed in a correct ratio. So the width for the left image and the height of the right image should be `auto`.

But my problem is, that the div-container needs dimensions for showing. How do I do that, as I don't know both parameters?

**Update:** If I'm using `width: 300px` for the div-container, I can use `background-size: 100% auto` and this is working. But I don't know the width...

So what would be a good way to realize that?

```css
main {
  background-color: green;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
#left_image {
  background-image: url(images/left.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}
#right_image {
  background-image: url(images/right.jpg);
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="left_image"></div>
  <div id="right_image"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Techniques described here may help: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ Particularly the [`background-size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj127316.aspx) property.

Comment: background-size takes width and height iirc.

Comment: I tried to use background-size, but I didn't get it correctly. As far as I know just the IE8 can't use background-size, right? I leave the dimensions of the div-elements as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `<img>`?

```
<main>
  <img src="images/left.jpg" id="left_image">
</main>

#left_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This would also work for IE8. Don't know an advantage for using `background-image`...